# Como devo organizar meus controllers utilzando a metodologia SOLID?

Tags: php, laravel

Atualmente estou desenvolvendo um projeto e notei que meus controllers estão responsáveis por mais de uma atividade.

Pensando sobre isso lembrei sobre o Hangout da Comunidade Laravel Brazil sobre SOLID.

O problema é que não sei qual a melhor maneira de organizar os controllers... atualmente há o seguinte caso:

### ContatosController

Responsabilidades:

- CRUD (index, create, store, edit, update, destroy)
- Importar contatos de outro sistema por CSV (3 métodos)
- Exportar contatos para outros sistemas em CSV (2 métodos)
- Buscar contatos através de filtros simples ou complexos (2 métodos)

### Como eu deveria organizar este controller?

- ContatosController
- ContatoImportacoesController ou ContatosIOController
- ContatosFiltrosController

Algo assim?

---

Se algo não foi bem explicado ou precisarem de mais detalhes, me avisem.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Relevante: http://qualityisspeed.blogspot.com.br/2014/08/why-i-dont-teach-solid.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma diferença bastante sutil no Princípio da Responsabilidade Única que causa esse tipo de questionamento.

Ter Responsabilidade Única não é **restringir** o objeto a fazer uma única coisa e sim impedir que ela faça coisas **além** do contexto mais próximo que se tem como intenção ao iniciar sua codificação.

No seu caso, você tem o contexto de **Contatos**. Um *Controller* de Contatos deve controlar tudo sobre Contatos e só.

Mas controlar tudo sobre Contatos inclui tudo o que você citou, desde o CRUD até a busca e a importação/exportação.

Porém, não será o *Controller* propriamente dito quem importará/exportará os dados, por exemplo. Ele vai apenas intermear a escolha do usuário feita na GUI (View) e o produto final através da Requisição feita.

Nesse caso, o **Importador** é uma sim classe separada, mas não é um *Controller*, pelo menos não na definição convencional, pois um Importador deve possibilitar importar não apenas contatos, mas qualquer tipo de informação.

Não estou certo se com **métodos** você se referiu realmente a métodos de classe ou a formas de importação, mas supondo que tenha sido quanto a formas de importação, isso sequer é responsabilidade do Importador em si.

O Importador por sua vez oferecer uma interface (não visual, claro) para o *Controller* trabalhar, mas as reais rotinas de importação, ou melhor [as estratégias](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy/php) de análise do input (CSV, TXT, XML...) são outras classes mais, todas sob uma interface reguladora.

Em código, teríamos algo mais ou menos assim:

```
class ContactsController {

    // GUIs

    public function index() {}
    public function create() {}
    public function edit() {}
    public function delete() {}

    public function search() {}

    public function import() {}
    public function export() {}

    // Actions

    public function indexAction() {}
    public function createAction() {}
    public function editAction() {}
    public function deleteAction() {}

    public function searchAction() {}

    public function importAction() {

        $file   = ( isset( $_POST['file'] ) ? $_POST['file'] : NULL );
        $method = ( isset( $_POST['method'] ) ? $_POST['method'] : 'CSV' );

        try {

            $importer = new Importer( $file, $method );

            $data = $importer -> import();

            // Do something with $data

        } catch( ImporterException $e ) {

            die( $e -> getMessage() );
        }
    }

    public function exportAction() {}
}

class Importer {

    private $strategy;

    public function __construct( $strategy, $file ) {

        $strategyClass = sprintf( '%sStrategy.php', $strategy );

        if( ! class_exists( $strategyClass ) {

            throw new ImporterException(

                sprintf( 'Importer Strategy %s does not exist', $strategy )
            );
        }

        $this -> strategy = new $strategyClass( $file );
    }

    public function import() {
        return $this -> strategy -> import();
    }
}

class CSVStrategy implements ImporterInterface {

    private $file;

    public function __construct( $file ) {

        $this -> file =& $file;
    }

    public function import() {

        // Do something with $this -> file and return
    }
}

interface ImporterInterface{

    public function import();
}
```

> O fragmento de código acima serve unicamente para fins didáticos e, por isso, não foi devidamente testado ou mesmo otimizado, podendo, inclusive, podem apresentar erros de sintaxe

Comment: Certo. Então eu posso manter o que já tenho dentro do controller, a diferença é que ele vai utilizar outros recursos para prosseguir a requisição. Seria mais ou menos isso?

Comment: Pra responder com toda certeza eu precisaria saber se o Laravel tem algum tipo de *coding standards* dentre eles organização e estruturação. Normalmente, se não é (M)odel, (C)ontroller ou (V)iew, não faz parte dos diretórios principais da aplicação. Estes, a partir da raiz do site, costumam ficar num diretório à parte, muitas vezes chamado de **vendor** e subdivididos por desenvolvedor (ZF, Symfony, Smarty...), inclusive seu próprio.

Comment: Certo. Eu preciso entender isso melhor... vou esperar outros pontos de vistas e dar uma pesquisada antes de fechar a questão. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado.

Comment: Vi alguns vídeos do Jeffrey Way no Laracasts e sua lógica bate com alguns pontos que ele apresentou. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar :)